# VBA - Shell, Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure - Thunderbird Email with HTML table

Tags: excel, vba, shell, thunderbird

I have a VBA code which allows to create an email(Thunderbird) and in email body appers HTML table based on cell values. Everythings works fine, but only until table has less then 19 rows and 24 columns. Then pops up Run Time Error 5 - line with Call Shell.

Here code for HTML Table(found in Net):

```
Function create_table(rng As Range) As String 

Dim mbody As String
Dim mbody1  As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


mbody = "<TABLE width=""30%"" Border=""1"", Cellspacing=""0""><TR>" ' configure the table

'create Header row
For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    mbody = mbody & "<TD width=""100"", Bgcolor=""#000000"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:12px"">" & rng.Cells(1, i).Value & "&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>"
Next

' add data to the table
For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
    mbody = mbody & "<TR>"
    mbody1 = ""
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    mbody1 = mbody1 & "<TD width=""80"", Align=""Center""><p style=""font-size:12px"">" & rng.Cells(i, j).Value & "</TD>"
    Next
    mbody = mbody & mbody1 & "</TR>"
Next

create_table = mbody
End Function
```

Code for email:

```
email = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
subj = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
body = "Hello" & "<br><br>" & _
create_table(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion) & "</Table></Table>"
thund = "Thunderbird path" & _
        " -compose " & """" & _
        "to='" & email & "'," & _
        "cc='" & cc & "'," & _
        "bcc='" & bcc & "'," & _
        "subject='" & subj & "'," & _
        "body='" & body & "'" & """"

Call Shell(thund, vbNormalNoFocus)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
```

Is there any limition? Is it possible to change it?

Comment: ? , 2 things to look at, , length of thund string and the contents of the cells, specially if they contain single or double quotes

Comment: Try using `Option Explicit` and see if it shows up any parsing errors.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Comment: That `Application.Wait` looks suspicious it could be a timing problem.

Comment: I tried Option Explicit and removed Application.Wait, but still the same error.

Comment: Seems like thund length is too long. I found that, cmd line has limitaion of 8191 characters. After deleting piece of code - Align=""Center", code worked. Now need to figure out how to adjust code to 8191 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird allows using a file for the body with the message parameter, use that instead of the body parameter

```
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fname = FSO.GetTempName & ".html"
    Set FileToCreate = FSO.CreateTextFile(fname)
    FileToCreate.Write body
    FileToCreate.Close

    
    Email = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
    subj = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    body = "Hello" & "<br><br>" & _
    create_table(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion) & "</Table></Table>"
    thund = "Thunderbird path" & _
            " -compose " & """" & _
            "to='" & Email & "'," & _
            "cc='" & cc & "'," & _
            "bcc='" & bcc & "'," & _
            "subject='" & subj & "'," & _
            "message='" & fname & "'" & """"
    
    Call Shell(thund, vbNormalNoFocus)
    Kill fname
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
```

Comment: Seems like good idea. Do you have any source of information how this work? I never did it, so I need better understaing.

Comment: The answer above already does it!!!